# Verifiy my answer: Is this a pure nash equilbirum

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
  &  \text{Player $\quad$ 2}  \\
\hline
  & -2 & 8 \\
Player \quad 1  & 6 &-6  \\
  \end{array}
$$

$8$ us a pure nash equilibrium because it is where best response functions for each player intersect. And I have worked it out for mixed strategies.

Comment: Are these payoffs meant to be symmetric? So $\{U, L\}$ gives payoff 8 to player 1 and 8 to player 2?

Comment: Yes the payoffs are symmetrics

Answer (score 0):

$\{U, R\}$ is a pure strategy NE as is $\{D,L\}$.  You can verify this by fixing one strategy at a time for the two players and looking at what each's best response is: assuming P1 players $U$, P2's BR is $R$, hence it gets one dot; it gets another because if  P2 plays $R$, P1's BR is $U$.  Any square with two dots after youve gone through all strategies is a pure strategy NE.